# When are views 'killed' in android?

Tags: android, android-gui

When are the view's 'killed' and no more exist in Android ?

For example, suppose I have an asynctask and I run some network related stuff in the `doInBackground()` method. Then, I need to update my UI views in the `onPostExecute()` method.
Assume my `doInBackground()` took a while and while it was being processed the user moved back or even pressed the home button. The task will continue because doInBackground runs on a seperate thread, however, once it is finished and onPostExecute is called to update the views, the views might not be there.

1. Even if the activity is not visible (either gone to home screen, or another activity), what happens when the views try to get accessed and modifed ? How long do they stay in the 'heap/memory/whatever', do they get garbage collected after onDestroy ? or they stay around after that ?

I know a way to not get into this hastle is to use a switch that gets turned on and off inside onResume and onStop and check it before updating the views in onPostExecute, but I am unsure if this is solid approach applied in the android apps ? if not, what is the suggested way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `view` inside an activity can be considered like any other `object` within the activity class. It will stay in the memory as long as it is referenced by the some other `object`. This object could be another `view` or `activity`. This means the view will be gone if:

1) The `activity` or the `parent view` remove it `removeView()` from the view tree thus no one keeps a reference to it.

2) The `activity` or `parent view` that contain the view are destroyed/gone from the memory.

> If the activity is not visible (either gone to home screen, or another
>   activity), what happens when the views try to get accessed and modifed
>   ? How long do they stay in the 'heap/memory/whatever', do they get
>   garbage collected after onDestroy ? or they stay around after that ?

You can access the view, as long as your activity is available. And you can find more about that by reading the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

When you try to access a view that is gone from the memory, you will get a `NullPointerException`. The simple & solid way how you can handle `onPostExecute` is by checking for null before updating, example:

```
// inside onPostExecute
if(textView != null) {
   textView.setText("Background Method Finished");
}
```

The advantage of this approach is:

1) You do not have to explicitly keep track of *show/hide*.

2) Sometimes, view is not on the screen does not mean that it gone from the memory. For example, let say your `AsyncTask` finishes while your activity is `paused/stopped` not `destroyed`. In this case, you can still update the view, so that when the activity is `resumed` the update is visible and is not lost.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel async task when user leave from that activity. After cancelled task, onPostExecute will not called and capture cancel event in onCanceled event in async task class.

Comment: @bump what do you mean ?

Answer (score -2):

You have many ways

1.You can cancel the asynctask

2.You can kill the process,so there will be nothing in the menory or heap.

Comment: that is not my question.

Comment: view are associated with an activity ,and if you killed an activity views are also killed

Comment: -1 for suggesting killing the process - that is completely uncalled for.